# Google Cloud global location is not found?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm trying to create a workforce identity pool per this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/configuring-workforce-identity-federation). However when I get to the "Configure workforce identity federation" step and try to create the pool in the Google Cloud CLI, I keep getting this error:

```
gcloud iam workforce-pools create my-workforce-pool \
            --organization=<my org id> --location=global \
            --description="My workforce pooldescription." 
ERROR: (gcloud.iam.workforce-pools.create) Locations instance [global] not found: Method not found.
```

I can't find a single page anywhere that mentions global or the gcloud.iam.workforce-pools.create method not being available.

Comment: Has Google granted you access to workforce identity federation for this project?

Comment: You need access to workforce identity federation for this project then [set billing/quota_project](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/configuring-workforce-identity-federation#before_you_begin) using this command `gcloud config set billing/quota_project PROJECT_ID`.

Comment: @JohnHanley I wouldn't know how to request it?

Comment: Ask your Google Cloud account team to request access to workforce identity federation for this project. The account team notifies you when the project is granted access. That of course means you have already established a sales relationship. Contact Google Sales to get started.